# Strange icon appeared on the menu bar

Tags: icons, menu, .desktop

Well, days ago a strange icon appeared on my menu bar (it is like a box with a red circle inside of it).

It doesn't give any information either.

[image]

Comment: Please restart you system so the text will appear.

Comment: Can you think of an icon that used to exist that isn't there any more? It would be that application showing it's error state.

Comment: I have restarted my system a couple of times and the icon doesn't give any information in any restart

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I don't think i had another application in the menu bar, i was only used to chrome and steam

Comment: Does steam appear in that screen now? I heard steam was down yesterday. Anyway when the red thing pops up on my display it's when one of the battery's low and at the same time the battery icon disappears... therefore the battery icon changes to red thingy.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I don't think is related to my problem, this icon even comes when i boot the pc :/

Comment: @MaximilianoMilitzerUmaran Nothing happens when you click on it?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Nope, nothing

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this for the latest weeks on my systems and at least in my case its related to latest chrome builds, maybe an error/crash related to chrome's *appindicator*, i also observed that icon is still showing even after closing chrome, but is not appearing if I only use Firefox on the whole session.

Also if you turn off chrome's *run in background* option, it also does not reappear (losing fast reload and background running chrome-apps).

Comment: I tried what you said, and it didn't worked :/, it seems that it's not related with any app in my ubuntu

Comment: I mean that it is a possible internal chrome bug / error, and It is a pity that this does not solve your problem, in my systems I now keep the background chrome's processes off, and it has not been shown again, instead if I enable it, it appears again over time.